# How can I search through a data frame without for-loops?

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I have a data frame with positions where a bus has had the speed zero (standing still). I want to determine if this is due to traffic conditions or because it has stopped at a bus stop. I have a function that calculates the distance from the center of a bus stop to any other position (the function is called `in_circle`). If the bus has stopped within 20 meters from the center of the bus stop, I set `stop_type` to 1 and move on to the next point at which a bus has stopped.

The code below is working, but I have a big amount of data and the two for-loops take quite a while to run. Therefore, I wonder if there is a more effective way to write the code below.

Edit:
I added a picture of some rows of the data.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ekvqv.png

```
k=1
for(i in 1:NROW(df_bus_h_z)){
  # Save current longitude and latitude of the bus
  cur_lat <- df_bus_h_z[i, "latitude"]
  cur_lon <- df_bus_h_z[i, "longitude"]
  # Controll boolean
  stop_found = FALSE 
  #Search trough all bus stops
  for(j in 1:NROW(df_stop_all)){
    if(df_stop_all[j,"trip_id"] == cur_trip){
      # If the bus stopped at a bus stop
      if(in_circle(df_stop_all[j,"stop_lat"],df_stop_all[j,"stop_lon"], cur_lat, cur_lon) <= 20){
        df_bus_h_z[i, "stop_type"] <- 1
        df_bus_h_z[i, "stop_id"] <- df_stop_all[j,"stop_id"]
        stop_found = TRUE
        break
      }
    }
  }
  if(stop_found == FALSE){
    df_bus_h_z$stop_type[i] <- 0
  }
}
```

Comment: There are definitely more efficient ways using vectorized functions. Could you provide an example of your data?

Comment: Look into `fuzzyjoin::geo_join`. That should be much faster, and lets you define the max distance from any of the bus stop locations. http://varianceexplained.org/fuzzyjoin/reference/geo_join.html

Comment: @csgroen, I added a link to a picture.

Comment: @JonSpring, thank you, I will look in to that!

Comment: [You should not post code/data as an image because...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

Consider merging the two datasets which is often the vectorized counterpart of nested `for` loops between two data sets. Then, run an `ifelse` which depends on the return of unknown method, `in_circle`.

**Please note** below is untested without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1422451) and desired results. If needing to keep all records in either set, adjust the *all* argument in `?merge`. Also, adjust join fields as needed in `by` or `by.x`/`by.y` arguments.

```
mdf <- merge(df_bus_h_z, df_stop_all, by="trip_id")      # MAYBE SUBSET BY UNKNOWN cur_trip?

mdf <- within(mdf, {
           cond <- in_circle(stop_lat, stop_lon, latitude, longitude) <= 20

           stop_type <- ifelse(cond, 1, 0)               # NEW COLUMN
           bus_stop_id <- ifelse(cond, stop_id, NA)      # NEW COLUMN (POSSIBLY REDUNDANT)
       })
```